# Error using svc.fit(): ValueError: bad input shape

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have data about Parkinson patients stored in the dataframe *X* and whether a patient has Parkinson indicated by *y* (0 or 1). This is retrieved by:

```
X=pd.read_csv('parkinsons.data',index_col=0)
y=X['status']
X=X.drop(['status'],axis=1)
```

Then, I create training and test samples:

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=7)
```

I want to use SVC on this training data:

```
svc=SVC()
svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Then, I get the error:
ValueError: bad input shape (59, 22).
What did I do wrong and how can I get rid of this error?

Comment: print X_train.shape, y_train.shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problems with the definition of `train_test_split` Careful! `train_test_split` outputs the `X` part first followed by the `Y` part. You are actually naming y_train what is X_test. Change this and it should work:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=7)
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Either use this</strike>

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test =train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=7)
svc=SVC()
svc.fit(X_train,X_test)
```

Or this

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=7)
svc=SVC()
svc.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I prefer using the second one

Comment: No way someone should use the first notation.

Comment: yes, that's true. That's why I mentioned *I prefer using the second one*

Comment: Yes, but my point is, of course one can prefer to use whatever, because at the end of the day, there's no formal restriction, but the under good practices, the first option shouldn't even be an option.

Comment: I agree with you. Edited my solution